How can Allah experience time?
In verses 22:47 and 32:5, it says a day in the sight of allah is a thousand years by our reckoning. However science says time began with the universe and is an intrinsic part of it. So how can Allah meaningfully experience time when its something he himself created ?

Does Allah experience time?
The simple answer is no. Allah created time itself, hence He himself is not under it. This is also why He knows the past, the present, and the future perfectly. You can imagine Allah sees every instance of time from every angle at the same time, hence Allah would not miss anything.
The reason I can say this is because if Allah was NOT able to view all instances of time all at once, then it would mean Allah would have to remember something from before, or have to check to make sure about something from the future. Of course, we believe Allah is not like that, so we can say the Allah can indeed see every instance of time all at once.
Now, that out of the way, what does Allah mean by the verses you gave?
The verses mentioning 1,000 years
The first verse you gave, 22:47, is as follows:

وَيَسْتَعْجِلُونَكَ بِٱلْعَذَابِ وَلَن يُخْلِفَ ٱللَّهُ وَعْدَهُۥ ۚ وَإِنَّ يَوْمًا عِندَ رَبِّكَ كَأَلْفِ سَنَةٍۢ مِّمَّا تَعُدُّونَ
They challenge you ˹O Prophet˺ to hasten the torment. And Allah will never fail in His promise. But a day with your Lord is indeed like a thousand years by your counting.
- Quran 22:47 (Translation by Dr. Mustafa Khattab, the Clear Quran)

Note what the verse says at the start, "They challenge you ˹O Prophet˺ to hasten the torment", which is in reference to the Day of Judgement. The people of the Prophet (ﷺ) would mock him, demanding to bring the punishment upon them, if he was truthful. But Allah responds to them, that only Allah decides when the Day of Judgement is, and He will not fail His promise in bringing it. Then Allah says such a day will like be 1,000 years by our counting.
The fact that this day is the Day of Judgment is further supported by the verse 32:5, which you provided in the question, which states the following:

يُدَبِّرُ ٱلْأَمْرَ مِنَ ٱلسَّمَآءِ إِلَى ٱلْأَرْضِ ثُمَّ يَعْرُجُ إِلَيْهِ فِى يَوْمٍۢ كَانَ مِقْدَارُهُۥٓ أَلْفَ سَنَةٍۢ مِّمَّا تَعُدُّونَ
He conducts every affair from the heavens to the earth, then it all ascends to Him on a Day whose length is a thousand years by your counting.
- Quran 32:5

The verse mentioning 50,000 years
It should be noted that verse 70:4 mentions it will be 50,000 years, which may appear like a contradiction, hence it should be addressed briefly.

تَعْرُجُ ٱلْمَلَـٰٓئِكَةُ وَٱلرُّوحُ إِلَيْهِ فِى يَوْمٍۢ كَانَ مِقْدَارُهُۥ خَمْسِينَ أَلْفَ سَنَةٍۢ
˹through which˺ the angels and the ˹holy˺ spirit will ascend to Him on a Day fifty thousand years in length.
- Quran 70:4

If we look at Tafsir Ibn Kathir, it is clear what was meant by this verse. He says that it will be like 50,000 years for someone who was blessed with wealth yet did not pay Zakah and withheld it, which makes them a disbeliever, as Zakah is a pillar of Islam. Providing the source here and explaining the entire hadith he quotes would be too long, so I advise you to read it yourself here.
The duration of the day of judgment varies from person to person. It will be terribly long for a disbeliever, as mentioned in all the earlier verses, but will be short for a believer, as per a hadith graded Sahih by Sheikh Al-Albani.
Basically...
Allah does not experience time, but we do, and Allah is saying that the Day of Judgement will be super long for the disbelievers. The Day of Judgement is one day, but it will feel very long or short to us (depending upon the person). It doesn't say  "1 Allah day = 1,000 human years", but says that day with Allah will be very long to the disbelievers.
I am actually not sure if I made it too clear, so if I did make something vague, or didn't explain something, or made a mistake, please point it out in a comment. Jazakallah Khair.

Trying to understand the question itself:

In verses 22:47 and 32:5, it says a day in the sight of Allah is a
thousand years by our reckoning.


By this the OP seemingly understands that Allah experiences time, which then means in the sight of Allah is considered a consequence of experiencing time more or less like other creatures. If I'm wrong mention it.


However science says time began with the universe and is an intrinsic part of it.


So the OP believes science define or understand time as an infrastructure of the created universe.


So how can Allah meaningfully experience time when its something he
himself created ?


Here the OP is seemingly interprets his experiencing time as being affected by, and so concludes a contradiction which reads: how is it possible that Allah be affected by something which He has created on His own. This is my understanding of the question, and my answer is regarding this understanding, if it is wrong tell me to improve it if I can.


The verses you mentioned are:
[22:47] وَ يَسْتَعْجِلُونَكَ بِالْعَذَابِ وَ لَنْ يُخْلِفَ اللَّهُ وَعْدَهُ وَ إِنَّ يَوْمًا عِنْدَ رَبِّكَ كَأَلْفِ سَنَةٍ مِمَّا تَعُدُّونَ
[32:5] يُدَبِّرُ الْأَمْرَ مِنَ السَّمَاءِ إِلَي الْأَرْضِ ثُمَّ يَعْرُجُ إِلَيْهِ فِي يَوْمٍ كَانَ مِقْدَارُهُ أَلْفَ سَنَةٍ مِمَّا تَعُدُّونَ
The second verse only mentions a day as long in duration as a thousand of our years, and returning to Him in such a long day does not necessarily has anything to do with Him experiencing such a duration as long or short, or even experiencing time at all.
The first verse however is more on topic as e.g. عِنْدَ رَبِّكَ is sometimes translated into in the sight of thy Lord, although it is also sometimes translated into with your Lord and can also be translated else how. However, none of these has anything which implies time experienced by Allah. For example in Quran Allah says: فَلَهُمْ أَجْرُهُمْ عِنْدَ رَبِّهِمْ translated into they will have their reward with their Lord this doesn't mean we are not now with Allah, as He is everywhere and nowhere, not experiencing place as we might happen to experience. Allah AWJ is the Creator, never bounded in time or space, but also remember that Allah the creator is even the creator of how we experience time, so that He knows and understands what feelings do the creatures have about passage of time.
You could probably refer to a verse like  يَسْأَلُهُ مَنْ فِي السَّمَاوَاتِ وَ الْأَرْضِ كُلَّ يَوْمٍ هُوَ فِي شَأْنٍ which is translated into Whoever is within the heavens and earth asks Him; every day He is bringing about a matter, and seems more probable to be interpreted the way you like, but again such an understanding is wrong ...
With all of these in mind, the first assumption in the question (that claims Quran says Allah is affected by time, or bounded by time), is not necessarily valid for someone to necessarily conclude a contradiction and, thus, that the contradiction is resolved apriori.
PS. that you said science says time began with the universe and is an intrinsic part of it, it is only partly true. The notion of time is not that clear that it sometimes seems in Physics, there are deep discussions on the notion of time and even beyond the material universe there yet can exist different meanings of time.

Didn't answer the question. Why don't you focus on what the verses mean ? For our purposes it's enough to know that time began. You are not an authority in physics so just accept it.

@SalmanSheikh, let assume I know nothing about physics and Islamic view on this topic, when the verses do not  mean Allah is bounded to time, where is the contradiction for me to focus on and answer? :)

Your saying they don't contradict doesn't make it so. Doesn't matter how many times you say it. If you don't know i will tell you

@SalmanSheikh, ok eager to see the contradiction, show me.

It's not a contradiction. It's a scientific error. You got the whole issue wrong. Allah experiences time. Allah is within time. Time didn't exist before the universe. Allah didn't exist before the universe.

@SalmanSheikh, wow .... Allah didn't exist before universe is so strange to believe in ...How someone who didn't exist make another thing which similarly didn't exist to become into existence? ... To me, Allah experiences time the same way He experiences our emotions like love, fear, happiness, and so on, He is the creator of those emotions and those who experience such emotions, He knows how we experience love and so He knows how we experience time, and He knows how any entity experiences anything: والله علیم بذات الصدور.

@owari I think what they're trying to say is that if Allah experiences time, then He wouldn't exist before the universe, which would be wrong, thus Allah doesn't experience time. But if Allah doesn't experience time, then it would be contradicting what the questioner understood by the verse.

@FarisMuhammad, Thanks for the hint, but he said It's not a contradiction. It's a scientific error. So I still don't understand the problem, and how is it considered a scientific error when he already said For our purposes it's enough to know that time began. You are not an authority in physics so just accept it. I doubt if the OP really knows what's really his question, or perhaps the problem is with me not understanding him. Maybe you and others can help him better.

Salamalykum Salman May Allah bless you, akhi the both verse that you have quoted like
"Yet they ask thee to hasten on the Punishment! But Allah will not fail in His Promise. Verily a Day in the sight of thy Lord is like a thousand years of your reckoning." - 22:47
"They challenge you ˹O Prophet˺ to hasten the torment. And Allah will never fail in His promise. But a day with your Lord is indeed like a thousand years by your counting." - 32:5
In both of these verses I have brought two different scholarly translative work but in both of them you can see that. It is talking about the punishment and it is talking about a "promised day" which is the "judgement day" that's What Allah is talking about it's talking about the Judgement day on that day the one day of there will be like a sum of thousand days of here and as for what science says there is no problem in that because it is not talking about this realm and reality of this world or universe, rather it is talking about that promised day which is the judgement day which will happen after this world or reality or whatever inside it will be perish so that's what it is.
Hope you got it May Allah make it easy for you, Rest Allah knows best.

Nope I didn't mention  the judgment day verse. Both of the verse I mention are unrelated to judgment day.

I have cited the verses too read the full verses akhi the first one starts with "Yet they ask thee to hasten on the Punishment! But Allah will not fail in His Promise." - 22:47  and the second is "They challenge you ˹O Prophet˺ to hasten the torment. And Allah will never fail in His promise." - 32:5 and you can check any of the contemporary or classical tafseer too Inshallah you will find the same look I have just cited a little one it's Imam AL Qurtubi's classical Tafaseer “On a Day the extent of which is a thousand years” which is the Day of Resurrection. Hope it helps you.

If 22:47 is about judgment day it contradicts 70:4 which is definitely about judgment day. In any case 32:5 and surrounding verses says nothing about judgment. Your quotation is incorrect.

No it doesn't contradict. Cuz for some ppl it will easy quick day, for some it will be 1000 years long and some 50k. That's evident from sahih hadith, prophet said poor ppl will enter parasite in 500 years, other hadoth mentions entire judgement day will be 50000 years long.

I mean I would say yes for this and even the Surah 70 that he mentions by saying that it is "contradictory" it is showing that he is just quoting randomly because Surah AL-Ma'arij was revealed because someone asked for the punishment for how long it will be and it is confirmed by mufassir consensus so about 50k it is literally talking about the punishment of usual day on disbelievers of what they did

Mufassirun consensus haha. Its just interpretation. Theres no consensus. Everyones interpretation is different. Like i have heard tafsir say 22:47 is one of the 6 days of creation too. Can you cite the hadith ?

Thanks for the advice. I'm not interested in debating. Consensus among scholars, often based on analogy (Qiyas) that they do while writing tafseer and when they write they use same usool they don't go beyond than that, is a key method in Islamic interpretation. For instance, the revelation period of Surah Fatiha is widely agreed upon. Disagreements on specific interpretations are common and often arise from different scholarly approaches and they show it in the starting that this Surah's consensus is not widely accepted upon. Please provide a credible source for your 6-day claim like narrators

https://islamqa.info/en/answers/2272/is-a-day-with-allaah-one-thousand-years-or-fifty-thousand-years. Heres one opinion that says six day. You think the islamic CONSENSUS means anything ? A consensus only works if you have a valid methodology. There's no consensus that shakespeare is the greatest writer, even though most agree, simply because there's no way to tell.

For anything well known, there are bound to be people who disagree. Muslims proclaim Muhammad (ﷺ) was the greatest from mankind, yet pretty much every non-Muslim disagrees. Looking at Tafsir Ibn Kathir, you come to conclude it will be 50,000 years for those blessed with wealth yet withheld it. The Prophet (ﷺ) said the day is to be longer for those who disbelieve, but will be as long as the time from Dhuhr to Asr for a believer.

So I mean where do you find problem in this statement "Mu'min and Kafir are note same and equal in Allah's Judgement" even a beginner knows this Faris.
